# Calculus: Application of definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, self-learning

Suppose $a>0$ is a constant. Let $C$ be the curve $y=\cosh x$, for $-a \leq x\leq a$. Let $D$ be the region bounded by $C$, $|x| = a$ and the $x$-axis.

1) Find the length of $C$

2) Find the area of the surface obtained by rotating $C$ about the $x$-axis

3) Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating $D$ about the $y$-axis

For 1), is it $\sinh a$ ?

For 2), is it $2\pi a + \pi \sinh (2a)$ ?

Would anyone mind telling me how to solve the above problems? I really have no idea.

Comment: Intuitively, you just need to understand what integration does in these situations. For a short segment, you have the Pythagorean theorem $dl=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$. Then just integrate this segment length to get the full length. The area needs a similar thought experiment (a short strip of the surface has a width equal to the segment length, and the length of the circumference of the circle - then you integrate). For 3), just add together some thin circular discs (cylinders with height dy).

All this should be readily available in high school textbooks and online (wiki, mathworks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) the arc length of C is given by

$L = \int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1+[y'(x)]^2}dx = 2\int_0^a\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}dx =2\int_0^a\cosh(x)dx = 2\sinh(a)   $